# Invoice database on Google script - export and email multiple invoices from database [export error]

Tags: duplicates, save, export

I'd like to preface this with "I am not a trained coder", I've tried to teach myself as I go along so any tips would be helpful.

I'm creating an invoice generator for my teaching business. The document consists of "Generator" which contains the following data starting from column A: Client Email, Client Name, Invoice Number (clientID), Item, Unit Price, Quantity, Total Price. I have the following code that loops through the database, inputting the correct data in the other sheet "Generator Invoice". "Generator Invoice" retrieves the clientID via =VLOOKUP and fills in information in "Generator Invoice" using =FILTER.

The following code should fill the invoice, export the invoice as a PDF, save the PDF to a Google Drive folder, then send an email to the correct recipient email with the correct PDF attached.

The problem is when I have multiple items on the same spreadsheet. The invoice has the correct data in the correct fields, but it exports it twice, and then emails it twice.

```
function SaveAndSendPDFs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shtInvoice = ss.getSheetByName("Generator Invoice");
  var shtGenerator = ss.getSheetByName("Generator");
  var LastRow = shtGenerator.getRange(3, 2).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var dataRange = shtGenerator.getRange(3, 1, LastRow - 1, 8);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var recipientEmail = data[i][0];
    var clientName = data[i][1];
    var clientID = data[i][2];

    var pdfFileId = generatePDF(shtInvoice, shtGenerator, recipientEmail, clientName, clientID);

    var subject = "Invoice for " + clientName;
    var body = "Hello " + clientName + ",\n\n"
               + "Here is some custom text for your email.\n\n"
               + "Please find attached your invoice.\n\n"
               + "If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me.\n\n"
               + "Thank you!\n\n"
               + "Best regards,\n\n"
               + "Harry";

    var pdfBlob = shtInvoice.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

    var message = {
      to: recipientEmail,
      subject: subject,
      body: body,
      attachments: [pdfBlob]
    };
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  }
  
  shtGenerator.showSheet();
}

function generatePDF(shtInvoice, shtGenerator, recipientEmail, clientName, clientID) {
  shtInvoice.getRange("B11").setValue(clientName);

  var fileName = "0" + clientID + " " + clientName;
  shtGenerator.hideSheet();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("PDF Invoices").next();
  var pdfBlob = shtInvoice.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');

  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(pdfBlob);
  pdfFile.setName(fileName);

  return pdfFile.getId();
}
```